# Is the Cerebrate player-character in Brood War still alive?

Tags: starcraft-series

At the beginning of the Zerg portion of Starcraft: Brood War, Kerrigan tells you (a Cerebrate) that she "freed you from the control of the Overmind", and that she would let you live if you "served her willingly".

However there's no mention of the Cerebrates in Starcraft 2 (both Wings of Liberty and Heart of the Swarm) at all. Indeed:

> the Cerebrates appear to be superseded by the Broodmothers, such as Zagara

Is there any canon reference as to whether the Cerebrates are still alive (or at least the one you control)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally I thought you (Terran PC) killed the PC Cerebrate in one of the Blizzard downloadable maps, or non-canon expansions.  However, while digging, I found this interview: [BlizzCon 2007 StarCraft Lore Panel](https://web.archive.org/web/20090601005621/http://sclegacy.com/feature/22-bc07/288-blizzcon-2007-starcraft-lore-panel).

The relevant quote from Chris Metzen:

> Metzen: “…since Brood War there’s only one mind controlling the Zerg (as far as anyone knows). After Brood War **she whacked out all the (remaining) cerebrates**, so as far as anyone knows she is in sole control of the swarm. But that sure is an interesting theme *wink wink*” (bold emphasis mine).

Seems harsh to kill your personal Cerebrate, but that's the Queen B of the Universe for you, I suppose.